# waiting for scene to be fully rendered in cesium

Tags: events, scene, cesiumjs

when loading kml datasource, I want to display a loading image until it can be visualized in the viewer or scene.
I tried to handle:

- `viewer.dataSources.dataSourceAdded` event but it is fired very early, that is to say, the loading image disappears before the datasource can be visualized
- the issue is the same with

  `viewer.dataSources.add(datasource).then(function(){ clearLoader(); } )`

Please anyone can help
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
viewer.dataSource.add(datasource); // add empty datasource.
datasource.load(url).then(function () { clearLoader(); });
```

The `.add` function returns immediately, even with an empty data source.  But the `.load` function returns a promise that will resolve once the data source is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Update (i.e. `Cesium.viewer.dataSources.add()`):

> DataSourceCollection:
>
> add(dataSource) → Promise.
>
> Adds a data source to the collection.
>
> ...
>
> **Returns: A Promise that resolves once the data source**
>   **has been added to the collection.**

(https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/DataSourceCollection.html#add)

Then use the Promise `.then()` as described in the other answer.

Comment: Hmm... `Cesium.viewer` does have `.flyTo()` and `.zoomTo()` (https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Viewer.html?classFilter=viewer#flyTo)... Maybe I'll use that... It says, "If the data source is still in the process of loading or the visualization is otherwise still loading, this method waits for the data to be ready before performing the flight."

Comment: **Works!** ^^^^^